# Client-Side Validation on onBlur

Tags: html, validation

So letting the browser validate input fields when pressing submit is great but is it possible to validate the input field immediately when the user leaves the input field?

I was thinking about calling the same validating function that is called on the submit button on the input fields' onBlur but I can't find out it this is possible.

Edit: Maybe the question wasn't clear. I know I can do my own validation in a JS function but this is about the validation the browser does.
Let's say I have an input field with type="email". I write *abc@.com* and press submit. The browser will then validate the input and prompt me with an error that the email is not valid and needs a domain. I want this warning to be present when leaving the input field.

So to sum up, I want to call the validation used by the browser - not my own.

Comment: This is the default behavior. At least in Firefox. If you type an invalid value an blur out of the field, it is given a default "invalid state's" red border.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript function for that like

```
<input type="text" id="sample-text" onblur="myFunction()">
```

Or use jQuery as

```
$(document).off("blur","#sample-text").on("blur","#sample-text", function(){
    //Call your function here or write validation logic here
})
```